# How can I login as any user without having to grant access?

Tags: grant-login-access

My Profile is System Administrator in the Salesforce org(sandbox). Is there any way to login as any other User without the Grant access by the User?

Answer (score 5):

Per the help article on the topic: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=controlling_login_access.htm

> 1. From Setup, enter Login Access Policies in the Quick Find box, then select Login Access Policies.
> 2. To allow Salesforce admins to log in as any user in the org without first asking them to grant access, enable Administrators Can Log in as Any User.

Comment: To enable this feature- System Admin needs to raise a case explicitly in Salesforce. And then, System Admin will get the feature to enable 'Grant Login  access for all internal Salesforce users.

Comment: The article doesn't mention the need to raise a case and I have not had to ever do that but if that's what you need to do to access the feature, then you've got your solution path.